# How can I programmatically put together some UIImages to have one big UIImage?

Tags: ios

This is my code:

```
- (void)scrollViewDidEndScrollingAnimation:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{

// at this point the webView scrolled to the next section

// I save the offset to make the code a little easier to read
CGFloat offset = _webPage.scrollView.contentOffset.y;

UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(_webPage.bounds.size, NO, 0);

[_webPage.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
viewImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();


UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(viewImage, nil, nil, nil);   

// if we are not done yet, scroll to next section
if (offset < _webPage.scrollView.contentSize.height)
{
    [_webPage.scrollView scrollRectToVisible:CGRectMake(0, _webPage.frame.size.height+offset, _webPage.frame.size.width, _webPage.frame.size.height) animated:YES];
}
}
```

In which I save an undefined number of screenshots `(UIImages)` by scrolling the `web view`. This works, I have in my photo gallery all the parts of the web page.
But I don't want parts, I want ONE long UIImage. So how do I put (one by one?) my UIImages together?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can write a UIImage category to do that

`UIImage+Combine.h`

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface UIImage (Combine)

+ (UIImage*)imageByCombiningImage:(UIImage*)firstImage withImage:(UIImage*)secondImage;

@end
```

`UIImage+Combine.m`

```
#import "UIImage+Combine.h"


@implementation UIImage (Combine)

+ (UIImage*)imageByCombiningImage:(UIImage*)firstImage withImage:(UIImage*)secondImage {
    UIImage *image = nil;

    CGSize newImageSize = CGSizeMake(MAX(firstImage.size.width, secondImage.size.width), firstImage.size.height + secondImage.size.height);
    if (UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions != NULL) {
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(newImageSize, NO, [[UIScreen mainScreen] scale]);
    } else {
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(newImageSize);
    }
    [firstImage drawAtPoint:CGPointMake(roundf((newImageSize.width-firstImage.size.width)/2), 0)];
    [secondImage drawAtPoint:CGPointMake(roundf(((newImageSize.width-secondImage.size.width)/2) ),
                                     roundf((newImageSize.height-secondImage.size.height)))];
    image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    return image;
}
```

and then you can call the function in your code with:

`UIImage *img = [UIImage imageByCombiningImage:image1 withImage:image2];`

This will draw a new image that has the width of the biggest of the two images and the height of both images combined. image1 will be at the top position and image2 below that.

Comment: For some reason, it doesn't work.
I do this:

imageContainer = [UIImage imageByCombiningImage:imageContainer withImage:viewImage];

every time. Is it right?

Comment: yes, you can chain multiple calls to the function in that way to combine multiple images. what kind of error are you experiencing?

Comment: I found it: I had to do: firstImage.size.height + secondImage.size.height in the CGSizeMake (MAX is not correct in this case).
But now it saves the images all in the same position, so one overlaps the other. :/

Comment: Ok, done. The DrawAtPoint is like this:
[firstImage drawAtPoint:CGPointMake(0,0)];
[secondImage drawAtPoint:CGPointMake(0, firstImage.size.height)];

You, sir, saved my life :)

Comment: sorry, i misunderstood your question. i thought you wanted to overlay the images all on top of each other. i edited the solution to fit your needs.