# How do I programmatically combine multiple UIImages into one long UIImage?

Tags: ios

I'm using the code from here [How can I programmatically put together some UIImages to have one big UIImage?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23649182/how-can-i-programmatically-put-together-some-uiimages-to-have-one-big-uiimage) to combine multiple screenshots into one large vertical image. However, I'm having trouble calling this function to combine multiple images together using:

```
imageContainer = [UIImage imageByCombiningImage:imageContainer withImage:viewImage];
```

How do I call this UIImage+combine category to merge the library of images together?

Here's my Code:

```
- (void) printScreen {
   // this is a method that starts the screenshot taking process

   // this line is necessary to capture the completion of the scrollView animation
   _webView.scrollView.delegate = self;

   // save the first image
   UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(_webView.bounds.size, NO, 0);
   [_webView.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
   UIImage *viewImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
   UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

   UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(viewImage, nil, nil, nil);

   // scroll to the next section
   [_webView.scrollView scrollRectToVisible:CGRectMake(0, _webView.frame.size.height, _webView.frame.size.width, _webView.frame.size.height) animated:YES];

}


- (void )scrollViewDidEndScrollingAnimation:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
   // at this point the _webView scrolled to the next section

   // I save the offset to make the code a little easier to read
   CGFloat offset = _webView.scrollView.contentOffset.y;

   UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(_webView.bounds.size, NO, 0);
   // note that the below line will not work if you replace _webView.layer with _webView.scrollView.layer
   [_webView.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
   UIImage *image1 = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
   UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

   UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(image1, nil, nil, nil);

   // if we are not done yet, scroll to next section
   if (offset < _webView.scrollView.contentSize.height) {
    [_webView.scrollView scrollRectToVisible:CGRectMake(0, _webView.frame.size.height+offset, _webView.frame.size.width, _webView.frame.size.height) animated:YES];
   }

    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageByCombiningImage:image1 withImage:image2];
    [[self theNewImageView] setImage:image];
    UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(image, nil, nil, nil);
    NSLog(@"%@ printScreen Image", image);
    NSLog(@"%@ printScreen Image2", image2);

   }
```

**Edit:**

At this point I've tried alot of different things. Im new to objective C development so I've been digging deep into the Apple developer docs and other good places for info like stack and lynda. 
Im seeing two different codes from the logs:  printScreen Image2,  printScreen Image, but i just cant get the function to call the new category.

I'm able to write all the images in separate pieces to the photo album and I can merge image1 or image2 into one image but not the both images or all images.

Comment: What's the issue? Provide a lot more detail.

Comment: Can I call 'UIImage+combine' function from within 'scrollViewDidEndScrollingAnimation' or should I create a new function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out! Right in front of my face the entire time. I needed to add the call to the category within the `scrollViewDidEndScrollingAnimation` then save to the `UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(image, nil, nil, nil);`. I probably tried a couple different version of this solution but I renamed some variables early on to align with my project which screwed everything up.